# Can I route to an error page from the HTTPInterceptor in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I am using Angular 8, and I have an HTTPInterceptor which intercepts every API call in my app. For the purpose of error handling and routing to `/error/401` page incase the API returns HTTP 401.

I have used `this.route.navigate(['error', responseCode]);` in the intercept method. I have the following route in the app module

```
{
    path: 'error/:responseCode',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
 }
```

The url is getting updated to `/error/401` but the component is not getting initiated. However, if I refresh the browser, the ErrorPageComponent is getting loaded and the message is displayed.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Or Are you using `changedetection` strategy?

Comment: There are no console errors.

Comment: Can you share the code of error component?

Comment: ```export class ErrorPageComponent implements OnInit {
   errorCode: string;
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url[1].toString();
    // errorMessage display logic 
  }
}```

Comment: This worked fine, after changing some logic in our html, which was loading data only after receiving some API response, which failed due to HTTP 503.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have spent sometime, investigating this issue, I would like to answer the question by myself.

It is possible to route to an error page based on the statusCode from the interceptor. I have done the following and it worked.

```
constructor(private route: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
....
this.route.navigate(['error', responseCode]);
```

Also, in the app-routing module, added the below snippet.

```
 {
    path: 'error/:id',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
  }
```